# My images wont horizontally align

Tags: html, css

I cannot get my `div`s inlined horizontally using `display: inline;`

This is my code:

```
 <div class = "links">
   <ul>
      <div id = "twitter">
         <a href = "#">
            <li><img src="images/twitter.png" /> </li>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div id = "facebook">
         <a href = "#">
            <li><img src="images/facebook.ico" /></li>
         </a>
      </div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This is my css:

I've told it to be `inline`, and it keeps being inlined vertically

```
#facebook img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#twitter img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.links  ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.links ul {
  background-color: rgb(0, 125, 210);
  float: center;
}
```

Comment: Note that [only an `li` can be a child of a `ul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). You'll need to restructure your mark-up for it to be [valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `flex` to `display` property in `.links ul` :

```
.links ul {
  background-color: rgb(0, 125, 210);
  float: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jad's answer is a solution, my answer is, instead, a bit of explanation.

```
.links  ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

This code will make your list elements inline. All 0 of them. You're using `div` elements instead, which won't be found by your CSS rule. You could change the rule, or the HTML, but one way or another you want the CSS rule to apply to the correct element type. (Michael_B is right that a non-li inside a ul is invalid HTML)

Comment: Huh. Somebody downvoted both my answer and Jad's, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `#facebook, #twitter{display:inline-block}`. That's all.

```css
#twitter img,
#facebook img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
#twitter,
#facebook {
  display: inline-block;
}

.links ul {
  background-color: rgb(0, 125, 210);
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <ul>
    <div id="twitter">
      <a href="#">
        <li>
          <img src="http://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Twitter-icon.png.png" />
        </li>
      </a>

    </div>
    <div id="facebook">
      <a href="#">
        <li>
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" />
        </li>
      </a>

    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```